# statsmodel.Tweedie.loglike returning NaNs

Tags: python, statsmodels

Whenever I try to compute the loglikelihood of a Tweedie distribution I only get nans. The following example has tweedie power p = 2 (which is a Gamma distribution) and the output of the Gamma as comparison:

```
import statsmodels as sm

aux_gamma = sm.genmod.families.Gamma()
print(aux_gamma.loglike(1000, 10))

aux_tweedie = sm.genmod.families.Tweedie(var_power=2)
print(aux_tweedie.loglike(1000, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.families.family.Tweedie.html):

> Loglikelihood function not implemented because of the complexity of calculating an infinite series of summations. The variance power can be estimated using the estimate_tweedie_power function that is part of the statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM class.

The only likelihood function available in this case is the extended quasi-likelihood function proposed by [Nelder and Pregibon (1987)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2336136?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). It can be used by setting `eql=True` inside the `.Tweedie()` function.